# Redirect http to https and subdomain to root domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to do properly implement a few redirects and since I am not an .htaccess expert I need some help.

I basically own a domain (domain2) that is set-up as a subdomain of another domain (domain2), which is connected to my shared hosting plan. I installed a SSL certificate for domain2 via cPanel and also installed WordPress to run on domain2.

I need to redirect all http requests to https, redirect the domain2 as a subdomain of domain1 and also make sure it doesn't interfere with the WordPress .htaccess stuff.

Here is what I have tried. The http to https redirect seems to work fine but I am still able to access domain2.domain1.com and it doesn't redirect me to domain2.com.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain2\.com\/" [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one rule below in your .htaccess.

Replace

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/domain2\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

With this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey, I just tried that but now domain1 redirects to domain2 and that's it. I need domain1 to be accessible and just have domain2.domain1.com to redirect to domain2 as well as all http requests to https on domain2. Really hard to get my head around this.

Comment: Your requirement is confusing. You need all non ssl requests to either `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` that are http to be redirected to `https://domain2.com`? or if it's `domain2.domain1.com` redirect to `https://domain2.com`?

Comment: Sorry about that! I need to redirect domain2.domain1.com to domain2.com. Then, I need all http requests for domain2 to be redirected to https. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok clear your cache and try my updated answer and see if that works out.

Comment: It seems to do the trick! However, in your answer you say it needs to be on domain1 .htaccess. This didn't work for me. When I added it on domain2 .htaccess it works! Is that right?

Comment: That was when I was unclear of the requirement. I updated the answer. You should be good to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93735/discussion-between-charles-ingalls-and-panama-jack).